# React Native Android - Facebook login pop-up disappears immediately

Tags: javascript, android, facebook-javascript-sdk, react-native

I've made an Android app with React Native. I have a facebook login with their sdk - it works well. I've tested it on many phones and it works.

On one user though - as soon as he clicks the 'continue with facebook' button, it starts loading, the window appears for like 200ms and then disappears immediately. The result is that he can't log into my app.

Any ideas what's causing this and how to fix it?

Comment: You can try to clean your app cokie and try again.